# auto detect new files in DIR and send them to google drive

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, google-drive-api, image-uploading

I am creating pdfs and sending them to a directory located in my website files. when these new files are created I want to automatically send them to google drive the user should not have to press any buttons. I have the google drive api set up and working with php using this [github](https://github.com/eduardocasas/Google-Drive-PHP-API-Simple-App-Example/tree/master/google-api-php-client) example, but do not know what to do next this is the last piece to having my site complete. Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Did you already read google documentation? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads it will help you.

Comment: welcome to stack please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask edit your question include enough of your code to show the issue and describe the issue in detail including any error messages.

Comment: What have you tried so far?